# Android : ListView onClick event in the tabs

Tags: android, listview, android-tabhost

I'm just a newbie in Android world.
I tried to add a ListView inside a tab (or actually in activity),
and each listview will be displaying another view that contains component such text, image and etc.
this components is got to be dynamic, will be set within the source program

listview layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="80dip"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" android:gravity="center">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/img" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/name" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight" android:textSize="18dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip" android:gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

onListItemClick :

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    try {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
        View detailview = factory.inflate(R.layout.top_detail,null);

        ImageView detailimg = (ImageView) detailview.findViewById(R.id.img_detail);
        TextView detailtxt = (TextView) detailview.findViewById(R.id.txt_detail);

        if (position == SUKIMA) {
            detailimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.sukima);
            detailtxt.setText(R.string.sukima_detail);
        } else if (position == TAJUUJIN) {
            detailimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.pu_tajuujin);
            detailtxt.setText(R.string.tajuujin_detail);
        } else if (position == LOVERS) {
            detailimg.setImageResource(R.drawable.pu_lovers);
            detailtxt.setText(R.string.lovers_detail);
        }

        this.flipper.setInAnimation(AnimationSanmon.inFromRightAnimation());
        this.flipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationSanmon.outToLeftAnimation());
        this.flipper.showNext();

        detailimg.setImageDrawable(detailview.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sukima));
        detailtxt.setText(R.string.sukima_detail);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

you could see that I'm trying to set image and text using setImageResource and setText, 
but after I run it, this text and image component didn't updated.

I'll be appreciate to the solution of this problem.

Kind Regards,
Aru

Answer (score 0):

You spend several lines of code inflating and configuring `detailview`. However, you do not then use `detailview` anywhere.

Comment: what do you mean with "use detailview" ?
Hmm .. I think I used it to find the ImageView and TextView from detailview.
please look the source below :

        ImageView detailimg = (ImageView) detailview.findViewById(R.id.img_detail);
        TextView detailtxt = (TextView) detailview.findViewById(R.id.txt_detail);


and the detailview is set on the ViewFlipper layout, so it have to show it after the animation is gone.

could it my implementation is not right ?